# cumulative percentile calculation in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, window, iterated-function

I have a dataframe like so:

```
|SEQ_ID |TIME_STAMP             |RESULT          |
+-------+-----------------------+----------------+
|3879859|2021-08-31 19:54:53.88 |25.9485244750994|
|3879859|2021-08-31 21:16:06.228|35.9163284302007|
|3879859|2021-08-31 22:28:46.306|41.9778823852006|
|3879859|2021-08-31 22:28:46.306|41.9778823852006|
|3879859|2021-08-31 23:12:08.058|39.9112701415998|
|3879859|2021-08-31 23:17:35.796|33.0476760864009|
|3879859|2021-08-31 23:47:17.383|60.2846145630007|
|3879859|2021-09-01 00:00:26.722|67.0690536499006|
|3879859|2021-09-01 00:00:26.722|67.0690536499006|
|3879859|2021-09-01 00:02:07.825|67.8424835205007|
```

For normal percentile calculation in pyspark I use the following:

```
df.groupBy('SEQ_ID')\
.agg(f.expr('percentile(RESULT, 0.25)').alias('Q1'),
     f.expr('percentile(RESULT, 0.50)').alias('Median'),
     f.expr('percentile(RESULT, 0.75)').alias('Q3'))\
```

But that takes all the data grouped by `SEQ_ID`.
I want to calculate the Q1, median, and Q3 for each row, using the rows above it.

```
|SEQ_ID |TIME_STAMP             |RESULT          |Q1   |Median|Q3   |
+-------+-----------------------+----------------+-----+------+-----+
|3879859|2021-08-31 19:54:53.88 |25.9485244750994|
|3879859|2021-08-31 21:16:06.228|35.9163284302007|
|3879859|2021-08-31 22:28:46.306|41.9778823852006|
|3879859|2021-08-31 22:28:46.306|41.9778823852006|
|3879859|2021-08-31 23:12:08.058|39.9112701415998|
|3879859|2021-08-31 23:17:35.796|33.0476760864009|
|3879859|2021-08-31 23:47:17.383|60.2846145630007|
|3879859|2021-09-01 00:00:26.722|67.0690536499006|
|3879859|2021-09-01 00:00:26.722|67.0690536499006|
|3879859|2021-09-01 00:02:07.825|67.8424835205007|
```

So the `Q1`, `Median` and `Q3` for the first row would be: `25.9485244750994`
For the 2nd row, the percentiles would be calculated with `25.9485244750994` and `35.9163284302007` and so on and so forth.

If I define a window such that

```
w=Window.partitionBy('SEQ_ID').orderBy(col('TIME_STAMP').asc()).rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,0)
```

Would the following code work?:

```
df.groupBy('SEQ_ID')\
.agg(f.expr('percentile(Pad_Wear, 0.25)').alias('Q1'),
     f.expr('percentile(Pad_Wear, 0.50)').alias('Median'),
     f.expr('percentile(Pad_Wear, 0.75)').alias('Q3')).over(w)
```

Comment: @ggordon
Thank you. yes, it does. It's pretty much what I expected. However, I underestimated the cumulative effect and I changed the `percentile` to `percentile_approx` since I have a very large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new "fake ID column" using [`monotonically_increasing_id`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id), then either group by it or windowing by it, it will run row by row

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I thought about using that, but it would load the entire dataset to the driver node and create a lot of shuffle writes. I tried using `row_number()` but it was still slow. The `window` function seemed to be faster. Although it was still 50 mins longer than if I had just used a `groupBy`